# Visual Studio ftp publish

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, publishing

I am developing some .net core code using Visual Studio.  I would like to use Visual Studio to FTP this code to an Azure Linux VM with .net core installed.  Right now I am using WinSCP to FTP the project folder to my Azure Linux Server and it works fine.  However, I tried Visual Studio FTP Publish but cannot seem to get it to work. I have included the connection profile for reference.  Is it correct?

[image: Visual Studio Connection Profile]